# Check if database is exists SQLite (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, uwp

I writing UWP app. I have PCL and UWP project.

I creating database like this:

```
public class CreatingBD
{
    private string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    public void Create()
    {
        SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn =
            new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
    }
```

After this I call this method when I launch app. Like this:

```
public StartScreen()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CreatingBD appdatabase = new CreatingBD();
    appdatabase.Create();
}
```

I need to check I have database oк no, how I can do this?

Comment: Create your path variable as before and use if(File.Exists(path)) { // File is there; }

Comment: Thank's for help@Kevin

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SQLiteDatabase
{       

    private static string dbPath = string.Empty;
    private static string DBPath(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath))
        {
            dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);
        }
        return dbPath;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fileName From LocalFolder. Please Create first a dataBase.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath(fileName));
    }


    //Installed Location.
    private static string dbPathStatic = string.Empty;
    private static string DBPathStatic(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPathStatic))
        {                            
            dbPathStatic = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, path);
        }
        return dbPathStatic;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fileName Path from Installed location. Note Add @ in path e.g( @"Data\Data.dta or (@"Shared\Data\Data.dta) if in Class Library), Make Data.dta Build to Content in Properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnectionPackage(string path)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPathStatic(path));
    }


    //Roaming Location
    private static string dbPathRoaming = string.Empty;
    private static string DBPathRoaming(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPathRoaming))
        {
            dbPathRoaming = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path, fileName);
        }
        return dbPathRoaming;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fileName Path. Please Create first a dataBase.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnectionRoaming(string fileName)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPathRoaming(fileName));
    }

    //CustomFolder Location
    private static string dbPathCustomFolder = string.Empty;
    private static string DBPathCustomFolder(string fileName, StorageFolder CustomFolder)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPathCustomFolder))
        {
            dbPathCustomFolder = Path.Combine(CustomFolder.Path, fileName);
        }
        return dbPathCustomFolder;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fileName Path. Please Create first a dataBase.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnectionCustomFolder(string fileName, StorageFolder knownFolder)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPathCustomFolder(fileName, knownFolder));
    }
```

Checking if file exist

```
 #region CheckFileExist
    public static async Task<bool> IsFileExistAsync(string fileName, StorageFolder folder)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await folder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
            return item != null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```